# Cryptographic properties of field multiplication

Tags: finite-field

While reading about [AES-GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), I discovered there is a multiplication over $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128}$). My question is about its cryptographic properties, such as:

1. Take a random element $X$ from $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128}$) (which is not $0$ or $1$). Multiply it with a constant $Y$ (say, the plaintext, which is defined over the same field, $Y\neq 0$). Given the product $XY$, is it possible to recover $Y$ (or some non-trivial information about $Y$)?
2. If the product $XY$ satifies some regularity condition (such as $XY=1$), is it possible to gain information on $Y$?
3. If multiple conditions like this are given, is it possible to gain information on $Y$? I mean, say for randomly chosen $X_i$'s, the product $X_iY$'s are given.

If the above problems are hard to solve, probably finite field multiplication can be used as a method for masking countermeasure for side channel (at least theoretically).

Comment: Unrelated to masking: worth noting that multiplication by a constant in $GF(2^n)$ is linear over $GF(2)$.

Comment: @Fractalic Oh, I see. That would probably mean, given $X\odot Y$ ($\odot$ is the finite field multiplication) and $X \oplus Y$, it may be possible to recover $X$ and $Y$. I will ask a follow-up question for better clarification.

Comment: @Fractalic **Update** My follow-up question is [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84418/cryptographic-properties-of-field-multiplication-continued)

Comment: while what you say is possible, I meant that the map $X \mapsto c \odot X$ can be expressed as a binary matrix.

Comment: @Fractalic That leads us to a new [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84428/solve-matrix-products)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking about the multiplication operation over $GF(2^{128})$; it turns out that, if we exclude the element 0, then the multiplication operation over that modified set of $2^{128}-1$ elements is a [group operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)); for example, inverses exist.

And, for any group operation $\odot$, we have:

- For any element $Y$, if we multiply it by a random (and independent) element $X$, the result $X \odot Y$ is random (and revealing it does not reveal anything about $Y$).

This answers your question one (with your question being modified by having $X$ exclude the 0 element only, not the 1 element)
.  Remember, 0 is not a member of the group (even though it is a member of the field; we deliberately excluded it when defining the group); in contrast, 1 is a member of the group, and avoiding it would leak some information, in particular, the value that $Y$ is not (because $Y \ne X \odot Y$
)

- If both $X$ and $Y$ are unknown, then revealing $X \odot Y$ does not reveal any information about $Y$

This answers your question two.

- Revealing $X_i \odot Y$ for a large number of random $X_i$ values also does not reveal any information about $Y$.

This answers your question three.

> If the above problems are hard to solve, probably finite field multiplication can be used as a method for masking countermeasure for side channel (at least theoretically).

Possibly, but it wouldn't be ideal.  For one, we had to deliberately exclude the 0 value; a real implementation that does masking can't ignore such a possible value; in particular, if you had a $Y=0$ value, masking wouldn't work in that case.  On a more practical note, masking would usually involve computing inverses, and while computing multiplicative inverses over $GF(2^{128})$ isn't that hard, it isn't exceptionally trivial either.